# Running colSums on Sparse (dgCMatrix) matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a large dgCMatrix, call it d:

```
> str(d)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:21925262] 15862 14723 9042 31101 753 953 1015 1377 1642 3603 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:6794881] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 33538 6794880
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:33538] "MIR1302-2HG" "FAM138A" "OR4F5" "AL627309.1" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6794880] "AAACCCAAGAAACACT-1" "AAACCCAAGAAACCAT-1" "AAACCCAAGAAACCCA-1" "AAACCCAAGAAACCCG-1" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:21925262] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

When I am running colSums, I am getting following error message.

```
> nU <- colSums(d)
Error in colSums(d) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you run `library(Matrix)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually it worked now. Never thought I forgot to add the library. Sorry for this mistake. Thanks a lot.